# Unexpected equal symbol error

Tags: r, string, date

I am trying to create a list where the column name is a date string coming from a list of strings. Let's say my list of strings is:

```
stringList=list("1-1-2001","1-1-2002")
```

I would like to create a list like this :

```
AList= list(stringList[[1]]=5)
```

So that I get something like this when I display it:

```
$`1-1-2001`
# [1] 5
```

Is this possible? This works if I write the string directly, otherwise I get error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "AList= list(stringList[[1]]="

Answer (score 1):

Names that are not valid syntax should be avoided.

If you really want this (why?), `setNames` might be easiest:

```
Alist <- setNames(list(1, 2), stringList)
```

You could also do this:

```
Blist <- list()
Blist[[stringList[[1]]]] <- 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, we need to use quotes or backticks to access *invalid* column names.

```
stringNames=c("1-1-2001","1-1-2002")

stringList <- list(5,6)
names(stringList) <- stringNames

#this gives errors
stringList$1-1-2001
# Error: unexpected numeric constant in "stringList$1"

#we can use backticks - ` `
stringList$`1-1-2001`
# [1] 5

#or we can use quotes - " " , thanks @Roland
stringList$"1-1-2001"
# [1] 5
```

Comment: You can also use quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, updated the post. My preference is using quotes for strings, and backticks for invalid column names, so they get coloured differently in RStudio.